# Best software to convert text (plain, pdf ...) into audio to use it like an audiobook?

Tags: open-source, library, offline, speech-synthesis, artificial-intelligence

Simple the title, if possible **no limitation**. (like limited api calls)

Being open source and working offline would also be a good option.

And good AI voices are appreciated of course!

If not a program someone maybe know about a good library?

**Thanks in advance for any time spend!**

Edit: Looking mainly for Windows and or Android.

Comment: What platform? Mac can do that natively, no 3rd party software required so long as a pdf is *actually* text & not an image.

Comment: Either Windows or Andoird, converting it on point with AI is also a choice vs making a long audio file out of it!